# How to convert List Of Objects containing list of String (inner list) to List of String

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have class like

```
public class RoleAccess {

    private String roleId;

    private List<String> apiIdList;

    public String getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(String roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    public List<String> getApiIdList() {
        return apiIdList;
    }

    public void setApiIdList(List<String> apiIdList) {
        this.apiIdList = apiIdList;
    }

}
```

I want to create a new list which will add all apiIdlist from roleaccess

```
List<String> apiIdList = new ArrayList<>();
for (RoleAccess roleAccess : roleAccessList) {
            if (roleAccess.getApiIdList() != null) {
                apiIdList.addAll(roleAccess.getApiIdList());
            }
        }
```

How can we do with stream api or which is best solution to do this?

I checked normal object list to list but I want to list of object and inner list to list 
I tried this

```
  List<String> apiIdList = roleAccessList.stream()
                          .map(RoleAccess::getApiIdList)
                          .collect(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, List::addAll);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```
List<String> apiIdList = roleAccessList.stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getApiIdList().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please take a look on the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) for more info about `flatMap`.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> apiIdList = roleAccessList.stream()
                       .map(RoleAccess::getApiIdList)
                       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                       .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```